# MS Access: Calculate difference when two criteria meet

Tags: ms-access, criteria

I have an MS Access related question. I have a table that looks like this:

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vno1.png)

What I need to do is this: 
1. Find deadline 29.01.2017 (first month of the year), 
2. look at the corresponding AccountNumber and SubAccountNumber,
3. find deadline 28.02.2017 (so the next month) that matches with the AccountNumber and SubAccountNumber of the previous month, 
4. subtract the Amounts, 
5. and display the result.

In this example (Table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vno1.png)): The first deadline of 29.01.2017 has the AccountNumber 1 and SubAccountNumber 23 as well as the Amount 400€. Looking for the next month that matches AccountNumber and SubAccountNumber, we find the value 300€. I would now have to subtract 300€ from 400€ and put this in the field that I have added (see also Table [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGnvx.png)).

What I have done so far is concatenate the two attributes AccountNumber and SubAccountNumber, so my table now looks like this:

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGnvx.png)

I thought it would be easier this way, because now I can look for the first month/deadline (29.01.2017), get the corresponding CONCAT, look for the next month/deadline that has the same CONCAT, and subtract the amounts.

Seeing as I am new to Access though, I am clueless as to how to go about this. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. If you think that my approach using a concatenation is not target-aimed or if I haven't made the problem clear enough, let me know.

PS I read online that Access offers an if-else statement - would that be an idea?

Answer (score 0):

That should get you there or very close:

```
SELECT T1.ACCOUNTNUMBER, T1.SUBACCOUNTNUMBER, T1.AMOUNT-T2.AMOUNT AS AMOUNTDIFF
FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table1 T2
        ON T1.ACCOUNTNUMBER=T2.ACCOUNTNUMBER
        AND T1.SUBACCOUNTNUMBER=T2.SUBACCOUNTNUMBER
        AND DateDiff('m',DateAdd('d',1,T1.DEADLINE), DateAdd('d',1,T2.DEADLINE))=1
WHERE T1.DEADLINE=#29.01.2017#
```

Make sure whatever date format you use with `WHERE` is a valid date format for your locale. Obviously substitute `Table1` with the actual name of your table.

I do not have an easy way of testing this so there may be typos.

Comment: Never format a date expression in SQL after the locale. Always use either the ISO sequence _yyyy/mm/dd_ or the "reverse" US format _mm/dd/yyyy_.

Comment: I only work on projects that are for the US market so I have no idea what happens with other locales. How would Access know if 2/3/2018 is March 2nd or February 3rd? Doesn't that mean that even the standard formats can be invalid based on locale? Or does it assume it is US even when that is not the default format?

Comment: SQL, VBA, and DAO expect the US format and accepts the ISO sequence. ADO only accepts the ISO sequence. Thus, the simple rule is to always use the ISO sequence - it will never fail. In the GUI, however, the format is localised.